# SQL Server Always encrypt collation incompatibility on insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, always-encrypted

I have a Windows Forms application that has been working for a long time as is and now I have to encrypt/decrypt some columns in the database. I made all the configurations on my database, configured my columns to be encrypted, changed column's datatype to `nvarchar(max)` from `varchar(max)`, created a certificate on Windows store, exported the cert for the client and now I am trying to do the job on client side.

I changed windows form application framework to 4.6, added `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` to my connection string, updated the `.dbml` designer but I still get the following error when trying to insert a value:

> Operand type clash: varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MCM_V2') collation_name = 'Greek_CI_AS' is incompatible with varchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'mydb') collation_name = 'Greek_BIN2'

I am using Linq for queries

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using non-BIN2 collation. Always Encrypted currently only supports BIN2 collations.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine):

> Always Encrypted is not supported for the columns with the below
>   characteristics (e.g. the Encrypted WITH clause cannot be used in
>   CREATE TABLE/ALTER TABLE for a column, if any of the following
>   conditions apply to the column):
>   ...
>   String (varchar, char, etc.)
>   columns with non-bin2 collations

Comment: Thank you so much - this was the problem for me.